# How to limit the numbers in 2 text fields in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to limit the user's option in the textfield to type only numbers that is less than 59.

Iv'e got a code that works perfectly on only 1 textfield:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    var startString = ""
    if (minutesTF.text != nil)
    {
        startString += minutesTF.text!
    }
    startString += string
    var limitNumber = startString.toInt()
    if limitNumber > 59
    {
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

But my code for 2 textfields does't work right:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    var startString = ""
    if (minutesTF.text != nil)
    {
        startString += minutesTF.text!
    }
    startString += string
    var limitNumber = startString.toInt()
    if limitNumber > 59
    {
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}
func textField2(textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    var startString = ""
    if (secondsTF.text != nil)
    {
        startString += secondsTF.text!
    }
    startString += string
    var limitNumber = startString.toInt()
    if limitNumber > 59
    {
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one implementation of the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method. So your second one (with the `textField2` name in the method) is never called. Delete your `textField2:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method.

Note that the text field is passed as a parameter. Use that text field parameter instead of hardcoding the text field ivar in your implementation.

In other words, replace the use of `minutesTF` with `textField`.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    var startString = ""
    if (textField.text != nil)
    {
        startString += textField.text!
    }
    startString += string
    var limitNumber = startString.toInt()
    if limitNumber > 59
    {
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that your logic is all wrong for doing the check. Your code assumes the user is simply typing and the cursor is always at the end of the current text. Your logic will fail if the user puts the cursor elsewhere or if the user has select some text and then types (or pastes) more text.

Comment: Yea I fixed it by your code. what if i got 3rd textfield and I want him to limit him under 61, and the 2 first textfield under  60?

Comment: Add an `if` statement that sees if `textField` is equal to the ivar for your 3rd text field.